# How to get hour by hour CMStepCounter activity?

Tags: ios7, core-motion, apple-m7

I am trying to figure out how to get a hour by hour breakdown of all steps activity for the last 7 days.

Right now I am successfully grabbing total number of steps for today using this:

```
     [self.stepCounter queryStepCountStartingFrom:sevedDaysAgo to:now toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(NSInteger numberOfSteps, NSError *error) {

    //Some code here 
  }
```

What would be a good way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is I run that same query seven times one for each day of the week with the appropriate time range. In my handler I save the results to a NSArray so each entry in the array is the step count for a day of the week. I hope that gets you started. Let me know how it goes.